# Keeping Score in python code

Tags: computer-science, python-3.4

What do I have to do in order to have a score board for my code because I need a score board. I tried a while statement but got lost there. Can you help me? So lost.

```
import random
def main_menu():
    option = input("Play the game (P) , View the game credits (V), or Quit (Q)")
    if (option == "Play the game") or (option == "P"):

    riddles = [
                {"riddle": "What walks on four legs in the morning, two legs in the afternoon, and three in the evening?",
                "answer": ["Monkey", "Humans", "Nothing Silly"],
                "correct": "2"},
                {"riddle": "What has roots as nobady sees?",
                "answer": ["River", "Famliy Tree", "Mountain"],
                "correct": "3"},
                {"riddle": " I am the ruin of men, and yet they lust for me. \
                I have no power, no strength, and yet I am the might of kings and armies. \
                I am hard as dragons scales, yet I flow like water. \
                Men dream of me, and yet once found I am cast aside. \
                I am a dancing rainbow, ever chased, never caught.",
                "answer": ["Gold", "Sex", "Mountain"],
                "correct": "1"}]

    print("Welcome to the Hell of Riddles!!!!")
    print("Hope you can think")
    random.shuffle(riddles)
    for riddle in riddles:
        print (riddle["riddle"])

        for i, choice in enumerate(riddle["answer"]):
            print(str(i + 1) + ". " + choice)
        answer = input("Choose the number of the answer:")

        if answer == riddle["correct"]:
            print("Congratz! You can think!!!")
        else:
            print("Not correct... Pathetic and disappointing.")
elif (option == "View the game credits") or (option == "V"):
    print("This game is brought to you by: Hailey Reisner and Ashleigh Woodard")
elif (option == "Quit") or (option == "Q"):
    print("QUITER")

print(main_menu())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a counter and add to it for correct answers. You can also create a counter for wrong answer

Of course you want to declare these variables first.

so the code to increment your counter would be like : rightAnswer += 1

```
if answer == riddle["correct"]:
        print("Congratz! You can think!!!")
        rightAnswer+=1
    else:
        print("Not correct... Pathetic and disappointing.")
        wrongAnswer+=1

print('Right: %d\tWrong: %d) % (rightAnswer, wrongAnswer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter, say, `score = 0`. Now modify your code as follows:

```
    if answer == riddle["correct"]:
        print("Congratz! You can think!!!")
        score++
    else:
        print("Not correct... Pathetic and disappointing.")
        score--
```

Now it is up to you to add more complications like whether score can negative etc.